# Add desktop notifications for Chrome or Firefox

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, desktop-notifications

I noticed that chat supports desktop notifications to notify you when someone pings you, which made me think that maybe the main site has this functionality as well, and I'd really like to use it in that case. But I couldn't find an option to turn them on anywhere.

Chrome notifications look like this:

> [image: example for chrome desktop notification]

Comment: I have ported the extension to a Firefox add-on as well. Mind if I change your title/tags to be more generic?

Comment: No problem. I'm responding immediately because I got notified by your extension. Thanks again! :)

Comment: **Is there** any reason why this features isn't implemented on stackoverflow website yet? I really would be happy If I knew it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I started writing an implementation using the Stack Exchange API, but noticed that the API is too slow because of cached results. So, I took another path:

I've created a Chrome extension which uses Web Sockets to get real-time notifications. These notifications are then displayed in a desktop notification.
10 dec 2012: I have **ported the Chrome extension to a Firefox add-on**!

Example:

[image: 1 unread messages in your inbox]

- **Source code**: [Github Source Code](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications)
- **Chrome Web store**: [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle)
- **Firefox add-on**: [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/real-time-desktop-notificat/)
- **Stack Apps**: [Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox ( Chrome / Firefox )](https://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-extension)

Comment: @satuon I just uploaded it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle

Comment: To-do for myself, create [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) listing.

Comment: Ironically categorized in 'productivity', _I love it!_

Comment: @RobW When I installed it, it said "No user ID found. Want to configure Desktop Notifications for the Stack Exchange?", I clicked OK, but nothing happened. Also, Chrome didn't say what privileges/access the extension required, which was strange.

Comment: @satuon Have you tried the latest version from the Chrome Web Store?

Comment: Yes, I was trying that when I got the error. I also get this message if I disable and then enable the extension.

Comment: @satuon I mean the *latest* version. I fixed some bugs and improved the UI since I posted this answer.

Comment: OK, this time it asked for permissions, and it gave me a settings form where I filled my user ID. Is that the only thing needed? It didn't ask me for password or anything about Open ID.

Comment: @satuon That's correct. There's no authentication involved, because I'm using Web sockets. The extension subscribes to the `<userid>-inbox` event, and will immediately get notified when your *notification count* changes.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm waiting to see the first notification :) Btw, why does it need this permission 'Your tabs and browsing activity'? Is it because it's needed for the desktop notifications?

Comment: @satuon No, it's only needed for **focusing windows** (after clicking on the notification to open it) and ensuring that there's only one options page open. To see the use of the tabs permission, look in the source code and search for `chrome.windows` and `chrome.tabs`.

Comment: @TimPost Response to your question in the Chrome Web store: Are you looking for an option to stop the extension? There's a stop button at the Options page.

Comment: @RobW Not really. I'm looking to limit alerts to only certain types of messages (mostly, if a user replies to a private moderator message) so that I don't have to keep checking the site after sending one. Those subjects can be matched easily with a regular expression, so perhaps allow a "only show this" / "never show this" (selectable) option that takes a regular expression for the setting? Ping me once you've announced it on Stackapps and I'll convert this comment to a more proper feature idea.

Comment: @TimPost I've posted it on Stack Apps already, link is in the answer above.

Comment: Is it possible for the extension to check if a tab with stackoverflow.com is already open and switch to it in that case instead of opening a new one?

Comment: @satuon Yes. That's possible.

Comment: The extension stopped working for me recently. Don't know why.

Comment: @satuon I updated the extension, and it works again (the Socket URLs were changed).

Comment: Can this be modified to show a tray "applet"? (Without desktop popups)

Comment: @ThorSummoner Could you post a new "answer" with an elaboration of your feature request? Do you mean a tray icon with a number, or something like that? If so, that is not possible in Chrome.

Comment: @RobW That's what I wanted. Or At least a stated icon, didn't have to be numbered. I've assumed that changing your tray icon whatsoever is impossible. Oh well.

Comment: This does not work, I never received any notifications, can you help?

Comment: @Devealte I received a notification in Firefox when you posted that comment. Have you correctly configured the extension?

Comment: I don't know, I'll check

Comment: @RobW Ok, I set it up, can you tag me in a comment so I can test it?

Comment: @RobW Worked, thanks for the add-on.

Answer (score 2):

I want this feature as well.

An "easy" way of getting this functionality is to create a Chrome extension and use the Stack Exchange API. Some relevant docs:

- [Desktop Notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) in Chrome extensions
- [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/)
- [Authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) - SE API

Nathan Osman (known as [George Edison](https://stackapps.com/users/18/george-edison)) has already posted an extension for showing inbox messages in a browser action popup - See [Stack Alert on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing) (source code on [Github](https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Alert)).
A few months ago, I [suggested](https://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing/3312#3312) to support desktop notifications, but it has not been implemented yet.

So, someone with time and knowledge, please stand up and create this extension :)

Comment: [This extension is now available](https://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox) on StackApps.