# What is the reputation requirement for Web sockets?

Tags: support, reputation, global-inbox, live-refresh, web-sockets

After receiving [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156050/does-stackoverflow-have-chrome-notifications/156095#comment448961_156095), I discovered that there's a reputation requirement for realtime notification updates: <s>Using my [Sock Puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1833747/sock-puppet), I checked that 90 reputation is not sufficient.</s>

- What is the (reputation) requirement for realtime updates using Web Sockets?
- What's the motivation for this requirement (including the rep. threshold)?

EDIT: I did not test properly. 90 rep worked fine.

Comment: Good catch.. maybe [Established User](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)? The motivation is obvious, to reduce server load. Millions of live connections are HUGE burden on any server. Edit: well, 101 reputation are enough, used account on other site. Are you sure that with your sock puppet account you don't get web socket connection? How did you check it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I just tested again, and 90 rep worked fine. I put the wrong user ID in my [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle/). I had to use `2055992` (the **SE** ID (I probably used the Stack Overflow user ID).

Comment: So I would say now for 90% of certainty that 10 reputation points are needed, being part of the [new user restrictions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user). :)

Comment: You should rename your Sock Puppet to **Socket Puppet**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no reputation requirement** for Web Socket notifications. I verified this by finding a one-rep user, and put his ID in the [Desktop Notifications for Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/9699?real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-extension) extension.

Then, I pinged this user... ...and saw a desktop notification. From which I conclude that web sockets are available for anyone.

I can also confirm that real-time inbox notifications (at the site) should be available at 90 rep. Probably earlier.