# Wouldn't be cool to have desktop notification?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, desktop-notifications

Wouldn't be cool to have desktop notification like those used in the chats for all the notifications (like new comments or new answers) ?

Comment: I suspect 'cool' isn't a good enough argument to add a feature. Did you have any rational reasons? =)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156095/155197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others agreed, and have already built this for you: [Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox ( Chrome / Firefox )](https://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox).

Go forth and install that! Or pick any of the other [notification apps listed on StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/notifications) to achieve similar results.