# Change favicon when there's a notification

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, favicon

I recently realized that it would be helpful to me (and probably other users as well) if a notification about unread answers would also show in a favicon, for example as a red circle in its top-right corner. Could you please add that?

Comment: This would get kinda annoying for anyone who keeps multiple site tabs open at any given time, because *all* of the favicons would change to have a red circle on them.

Comment: That would surely be unique (never seen any site with such feature), but also super annoying. No thanks.

Comment: I've seen JS libraries that (claim to) do this but I've never seen it used... agree it would be super annoying though. We do already get a "(1)" in the title text for feed updates, *maybe* something similar for notifications would work..

Comment: @ShadowWizard For what it's worth, my ISP's webmail client (Zimbra) and Reddit (maybe only with RES?) do this.

Comment: @BenN huh! Well, I still really dislike it. :) (the idea.)

Answer (score 5):

I dislike this idea, for several reasons.

First, it will it be confusing when you have a lot of tabs open. Which tab to open? If you receive a notification on Stack Overflow, will all tabs show a notification? Also those from other sites?

Second, some browsers cache the favicon for longer times. That will show the 'unread' notification for longer than necessary... Confusing.

There is already a good way to notify of changes: the title. It shows `(1)` when the question list is updated. Altering that to show notifications would be nice. Also, I like the suggestion to [allow desktop notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156050/245360), as some browsers support (just like in chat).

Comment: Absolutely - I typically have 30-40 SE tabs open at any time. I really wouldn't want this!