# Web page notification

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

When I receive a reply on a comment or thread I created or opted into on chat channels such as [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) or MS Teams opened in a web browser I receive a small banner that extends from the bottom vertical pane of the screen if I'm not in that tab.

I noticed I get a push notification when using the Stack Exchange app on my iOS device when someone comments back.

Besides the inbox icon at the top right hand side of the screen, is there any feature within Stack Exchange that can alert me regardless of what browser tab I'm currently looking at like what Slack and MS Teams do?

Comment: You mean [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156050/does-stack-overflow-have-desktop-notifications-for-chrome-or-firefox), right?

Comment: @rene - thanks friend I'll give this a try, it looks like what I'm looking for.